# Smallest amount within a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min

The lowest rating is decided using the following list (/ represent a new cloumn) and is dependent upon the rating company (MR, SPR or FR). The list shows which is the lowest rate in comparison to other companies

Ratings list
MR:

Aaa/Aa1,Aa2,Aa3/A1,A2,A3/Baa1,Baa2,Baa3/Ba1,Ba2,Ba3/B1,B2,B3/Caa1,Caa2,Caa3,Ca,C
SPR:

AAA/AA+,AA,AA-/A+, A, A-/BBB+,BBB,BBB-/BB+,BB,BB-/B+,B,B-/CCC+,CCC,CCC-,CC,C,D
FR:

AAA/AA+,AA,AA-/A+, A, A-/BBB+,BBB,BBB-/BB+,BB,BB-/B+,B,B-/CCC,CC,C,DDD,DD,D

As shown in the example below, if multiple companies rate a bond on the same day, the lowest must be chosen
How would I select the row with the lowest letter in?

For example:

| issue_id | Rating_Date | Rating | Rating_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2015-12-31 | Aaa | MR |
| 5 | 2015-12-31 | BBB+ | SPR |
| 5 | 2015-12-31 | BBB- | FR |
| 5 | 2015-12-31 | C | MR |

I would be wanting the following row as my output:

| issue_id | Rating_Date | Rating | Rating_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2015-12-31 | C | MR |

Comment: `df[df["Rating"] == "D"]` , where `df` is your dataframe

Comment: @AvenDesta How would I do this as a general approach, as I have a large dataframe where I am required to do this and the lowest value will not always be D?

Comment: if your letters value is identical to their alphabetical order, you could find the unique values by df["Rating"].unique() and sorting them and selecting which one you deemed desired.

Comment: `df[df['Rating'] == df['Rating'].max()]`

Comment: You can first do `df[df["Rating"] == "D"]`, and if this is empty, `df[df["Rating"] == "C"]` ... You only have 4 choices so it doesn't even need `loop` or `max `

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

#Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"Issue_id":[5,5,5,5], "Rating_Date": ["2015-12-31"]*4, "Rating": ["Aaa", "BBB+", "BBB-", "C"], "Rating_Type":["MR", "SPR", "FR", "MR"]})

#Intializing company ratings
mr = pd.DataFrame({"Rating": ["Aaa/Aa1","Aa2","Aa3/A1","A2","A3/Baa1","Baa2","Baa3/Ba1","Ba2","Ba3/B1","B2","B3/Caa1","Caa2","Caa3","Ca","C"]})
spr = pd.DataFrame({"Rating": ["AAA/AA+","AA","AA-/A+", "A", "A-/BBB+","BBB","BBB-/BB+","BB","BB-/B+","B","B-/CCC+","CCC","CCC-","CC","C","D"]})
fr = pd.DataFrame({"Rating": ["AAA/AA+","AA","AA-/A+", "A", "A-/BBB+","BBB","BBB-/BB+","BB","BB-/B+","B","B-/CCC","CC","C","DDD","DD","D"]})

#Spliting ALias and original
mr.Rating = mr.Rating.map(lambda x: x.lower())
spr.Rating = spr.Rating.map(lambda x: x.lower())
fr.Rating = fr.Rating.map(lambda x: x.lower())

mr[['Rating','Alias']] = mr['Rating'].str.split('/',expand=True)
spr[['Rating','Alias']] = spr['Rating'].str.split('/',expand=True)
fr[['Rating','Alias']] = fr['Rating'].str.split('/',expand=True)

#Character score of the ratings
mr["char_score"] = mr.apply(lambda x: x["Rating"][0], axis = 1)
spr["char_score"] = spr.apply(lambda x: x["Rating"][0], axis = 1)
fr["char_score"] = fr.apply(lambda x: x["Rating"][0], axis = 1)

#Conditional numeric score of each character score
mr["num_score"] = mr.groupby("char_score").cumcount()
spr["num_score"] = spr.groupby("char_score").cumcount()
fr["num_score"] = fr.groupby("char_score").cumcount()

#Lower case of all ratings
df["Rating"] = df.Rating.map(lambda x: x.lower())


#Code to find char and num score for each row of the dataframe
def find_score(row):
    if row.Rating_Type == "MR":
        mr_rating = mr[(mr.Rating == row.Rating) | (mr.Alias == row.Rating)].iloc[0]
        return [mr_rating.char_score, mr_rating.num_score]
    elif row.Rating_Type == "SPR":
        spr_rating = spr[(spr.Rating == row.Rating) | (spr.Alias == row.Rating)].iloc[0]
        return [spr_rating.char_score, spr_rating.num_score]     
    elif row.Rating_Type == "FR":
        fr_rating = fr[(fr.Rating == row.Rating) | (fr.Alias == row.Rating)].iloc[0]
        return [fr_rating.char_score, fr_rating.num_score]


df["score"]= df.apply(lambda x: find_score(x), axis = 1)
df[['char_score','num_score']] = pd.DataFrame(df.score.tolist(), index= df.index)

df_sorted = df.sort_values(["char_score", "num_score"], ascending = False)
df_sorted.reset_index(inplace = True)
lowest_num, lowest_char = df_sorted['num_score'][0], df_sorted['char_score'][0]

output = df_sorted[(df_sorted["char_score"] == lowest_char) & (df_sorted["num_score"] == lowest_num)][["Issue_id", "Rating_Date", "Rating", "Rating_Type"]]
```

Comment: Can I ask why it is 0 in the square brackets? --> lowest_rate = df_sorted['Rating'][0]

Comment: Sure, that is because we want to pick the first index of the rating after it is sorted basically. For example if the ratings column was `["A", "B", "B", "C", "D"]`, after sorting in the `df_sorted` it becomes `["D", "C", "B", "B", "A"]`, from that the index `[0]` will pick "D" as needed. I will try and add an explanation to it.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand! would this work for ratings such as BBB+, Baa1 for example? I'm guessing it doesn't?

Comment: No actually it won't Python doesnt understand the meanings of BBB+ and such. We can find a way out maybe, can you post a sample with such possibilities, or what all is possible? We might try and work around a way. Would love to try and help in it. @lds1

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully you can understand the context of it!

Comment: Okay so this is the complete list right? will update the answer accordingly to help you after a few hours (night hours here). @lds1

Comment: Yes that is the full list, and if a bond is rated by multiple companies on one day, then i have to select the lowest rating (there are seven different tiers for the ratings for each company which have been separated by '/'). No worries, thanks!

Comment: Just another quick thing, is a B band in one companies rating, always greater than C in another? @lds1

Comment: @lds1 edited the code for your reference, check the solution. Hope this will resolve your problem. I have added comments for your understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226874/discussion-between-lds1-and-srishtigarg).

Answer (score 0):

If the rating column only has values from A to Z you can simply get the (according to python) maximum value and select the rows:

```
df[df['Rating'] == df['Rating'].max()]
```